# Enabling textbox by means of checkbox with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Can you explain me how can I enable/disable a text box (that means, can or cannot be edit) depending on a combobox?
If the combobox value = 1 -> textbox enable; if combobox = 0 -> textbox disable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What combobox are you talking about? HTML only provides `select` elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `onchange` event of the `select` element. Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function select1changed()
{
    var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
    txt1.disabled = (select1.value == '0');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    Combo: 
    <select id="select1" onchange="select1changed();">
        <option value="0">Option 0</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    </select>
    Text: <input id="txt1" type="text" value="sometext" disabled="disabled" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Note: I marked `txt1` as disabled to handle the initial state when the page is loaded and `select1` is set to `Option 0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var combo = document.getElementById('combo');
combo.onchange = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('combo').value;
    var textBox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    if (value == '0') {
        textBox.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    } else if (value == '1') {
        textBox.removeAttribute('readonly');
    }    
};
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JnbwA/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily.

Make use of the `disabled` attribute of the text box like this

```
function enableField(val)
{
  document.form1.address2.disabled = val;
}
```

**Note:** `address2` is a textfield

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
<select id='abc' onChange="changeMe()">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="abcText" />
<script>
function changeMe(){
    if(document.getElementById("abc").value == "111"){
        document.getElementById("abcText").disabled = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("abcText").disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>
```